# Can Travis CI build matrix be "shortened"?

Tags: travis-ci

I want to test my project with:

```
php:
    - 5.5
    - 5.6
    - 7.0
    - 7.1
    - 7.2
    - 7.3

env:
    - SYMFONY_VERSION='3.0.*' dependencies=lowest
    - SYMFONY_VERSION='4.0.*'
    - SYMFONY_VERSION='4.1.*'
    - SYMFONY_VERSION='4.2.*'
```

... but some of the matrix combinations (6 x 4 = 24 rows) **doesn't make sense** (i.e. Symfony 4.0.* can't be installed with PHP 5.5).

I use the following and it works: is there a way to "shortened" this list? Maybe a regular expression or something similar?

```
matrix:
    exclude:
        - php: 5.5
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='4.0.*'
        - php: 5.5
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='4.1.*'
        - php: 5.5
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='4.2.*'
        - php: 5.6
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='4.0.*'
        - php: 5.6
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='4.1.*'
        - php: 5.6
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='4.2.*'
        - php: 7.0
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='4.2.*'
        - php: 7.0
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='4.1.*'
        - php: 7.0
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='4.0.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be shortened by minimising the matrix (so you don't need to exclude anything) and including extra jobs that require lower php version. E.g. below listed snippet would give you the same set of jobs as in your example:

```
php:
    - 7.1
    - 7.2
    - 7.3

env:
    - SYMFONY_VERSION='3.0.*' dependencies=lowest
    - SYMFONY_VERSION='4.0.*'
    - SYMFONY_VERSION='4.1.*'
    - SYMFONY_VERSION='4.2.*'

matrix:
    include:
        - php: 5.5
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='3.0.*' dependencies=lowest
        - php: 5.6
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='3.0.*' dependencies=lowest
        - php: 7.0
          env: SYMFONY_VERSION='3.0.*' dependencies=lowest
```